# Nested inner ng-repeat not displaying text, but updating $scope

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the inner ng-repeat to work. Each choice selection seems to be generating on the DOM according to batarang, but is not visible on the page. Not sure what I did wrong. Any pointers in the correct direction is much appreciated.

http://plnkr.co/edit/eoypUIYX07MpAvgT9wbT

```
<body ng-controller="qCtrl as quiz">
 <div class="list-group">
  <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in quiz.questions">
      <h4>{{item.question}}</h4>
    <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="selection in item.choices">
      <h5>{{selection.choices}}</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('qCtrl', function() {
   this.questions = allQuestions;
});

var allQuestions = [{
  question: "Who is Prime Minister of the United Kingdom?",
  choices: [
        "David Cameron",
        "Gordon Brown",
        "Winston Churchill",
         "Tony Blair"
  ],
  correctAnswer: 0
 }, {
  question: "Who is the President of the United States of America? (2014)",
  choices: [
        "George Bush", 
        "Dan Quayle", 
        "Barack Obama", 
        "John F. Kennedy"
  ],
  correctAnswer: 2
}];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `.choices` before `selection`:

```
<h5>{{selection}}</h5>
```